# Powershell variable's output

Tags: powershell, variables, header, output

[Using ISE]

I have: `'$($udvTest | Select ProcessName -Last 1)'` where `$udvTest` contains 5 processes as members sourced from `Get-Process`.

I get the following 3 lines:

```
ProcessName
-----------
svchost
```

But I want only the string "svchost" as output (e.g. for further processing). What am I overlooking that this little favour asked from PS seems so hideaous?

Answer (score 1):

```
(Get-Process | Select-Object -Last 1).ProcessName
```

would do the trick or for your example:

```
$(($udvTest | Select -Last 1).ProcessName)
```

Answer (score 0):

The pure Powershell way would be this:

```
Get-Process | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ProcessName -Last 1
```

or for your particular example:

```
$udvTest | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ProcessName -Last 1
```

Answer (score 0):

*"PS seems so hideaous"*

Actually, the fact that you see a table of information is a hint at one of the best things about PowerShell: objects.  These make your life so much easier than direct text manipulation.

Anyway, one way to get the information you want is:

```
$udvTest[-1].ProcessName
```

Since `$udvTest` is an array, you can index into it to find the item we want.  If you supply a negative index, PowerShell will count the from the end to the beginning, so `[-1]` means to take the last item.

The `.ProcessName` is another indicator you are dealing with objects and will get the value of the ProcessName property for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot! I see now that I have to give the property, 'ProcessName' to retrieve the pure value of it. Best!